# C++ Returning two variables from function, why is auto prefered?

Tags: function, return, auto

I,m trying to learn several ways to return multiple variables from a function and came across this way. I,m wondering what you could replace auto with in this case. For me at least auto is confusing and for now i,m avoiding it to a certain extent.

```
auto twoInteger() {
  struct bo{
   int m_three{};
   int m_four{};
  };
  return bo{10, 20};
}


int main() {
  auto [value1, value2] = twoInteger();
  std::cout << value1 << value2 << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. but Easiest Way is give argument as reference.

```
auto twoInteger(int &num1,int &num2) {
  struct bo{
   int m_three{};
   int m_four{};
  };
    num1 = 40;num2 = 20;
}


int main() {
    int value1;
    int value2;
    twoInteger(value1,value2);

    std::cout << value1<<' '<<value2<< std::endl;
}
```

if need more method.
[this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c-or-cpp/)